# Making HTTP calls from Hosted server to a local PC using Java

Tags: java, sockets, http, http-headers

I have an java web application hosted on a server with a DNS name. This application needs to make HTTP Rest calls to another application which runs locally on my PC over the internet.

Making HTTP calls from my PC to the hosted server works fine, and I am an able to get a response from it. I am also able to get the clients IP (local PC) address from the HTTP request object in the Hosted server using the below code:

`String ipAddress = servletRequest.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");

 if (ipAddress == null) {

      ipAddress = servletRequest.getRemoteAddr();

 }`

However the IP address returned form the above code is not my local PC's. It looks like its from my ISP provider.

My question is since the Hosted servers return a HTTP response over the internet. Can we make separate stand alone calls from a server hosted over the internet to my local PC ? Is there some information I can get from the HTTP Request object to get the address of my local PC to which I can make calls to?

Answer (score 0):

It will be the connection adress which ends at your router. Set the router to forward incoming http requests to your pc/application.

EDIT:

Iam not sure what you are trying to do. There is no safe way to really get the correct ip if you are not able to access the requesting computer. You wrote, you have access to your computer. Yust use whatismyip.com to get the right address. Then configure the router to forward incomming requests. If your ip may change, you can use a dns service like dyndns or simmilar to always have a unique address to reach your maschine. You do Not need to extract the information.

Comment: How can I find the connection address of my router from the HTTP request ? Will it work across a NAT internet service provider ?